# Sum of column values based on second column

Tags: mysql

Given the following data:

```
A B
1 1.1
1 2.45
3 1.1
4 3.1
5 2.45
```

I would like to write a mysql query that returns

```
SUM(A) B
4      1.1
6      2.45
4      3.1
```

So we determine all distinct values in column B, and then compute the sum of the values in column A per value value occurring in column B.

Note: there are an infinite amount of possible values that can occur in column B.

Comment: So you want to group by B and sum A. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Hannes Yes, that sounds right... (Sorry, I'm very unfamiliar with MySql lingo)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(column_A), column_B
FROM table
GROUP BY column_B;
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry for asking such a basic question... New to this.

Comment: How should I read this though? Because I would read this as "compute the sum column_A, and all entries of column_B, and then group them by the value of column_B". So then we would first get {(total_A, value_b1), (total_A, value_b2), ..., (total_A, value_bn)}, and after grouping by column_B, we get {(total_A, DistinctValue_b1), (total_A, DistinctValue_b2), ..., (total_A, DistinctValue_bm)}. But this is obviously not what happens? So how should I read this?

Comment: @user2520938, 1) Mysql will group same values of the `column_B` on the 1st phase; 2) it'll sum up values of `column_A` accumulated in each group; 3) print the sum of values of each group and distinct `column_B` representing a certain group

Comment: Keep in mind to place an index on the grouped column to improve performance.